# Leaflet Shapefile marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a problem with loading the leaflet shapefile on my page.
The shapefile is loaded correctly but the markers do not have the colors as in the shape file and the name of the shapefile does not appear in the list of layers but only the word shapefile. It appears to read the shapefile but not all information.

```
var watercolor = L.tileLayer('http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {});
var geo = L.geoJson({features: []}, {
        onEachFeature: function popUp(feature, layer) {
            var out = [];
            if (feature.properties) {
                for (var key in feature.properties) {
                    out.push(key + ": " + feature.properties[key]);
                }
                layer.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
            }
        }
    });

    var myMap = L.map('divMapID', {
        center: L.latLng(39.15097955985934, 9.019421210403138),//Valori prec: [39, 9],
        zoom: 10,
        minZoom: 3,

        layers: [watercolor, geo]

    });


    //data è un oggetto geoJson
    var base = 'testo.zip';
    shp(base).then(function (data) {
        geo.addData(data);
    });

    var baseMaps = {
        "BaseLayer": watercolor
    };
    var overlays = {
        "shapefile": geo
    };
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(myMap);
```

In the following image there is an example of what the shapefile with its properties should look like:

[image]

While in the following image it is how I visualize it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

About the name, you can change "shapefile" for whatever you want here :

```js
var overlays = {
    "shapefile": geo // change "shapefile" for "geo"
};
```

---

About colors, you must add a `style` function with your own logic when creating the layer :

```js
var geo = L.geoJson({features: []}, {
    style: function style (feature) {
        // your logic for creating colors here,
        // for example, a random color for each entity
        var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff)
        .toString(16)
        .padStart(6, '0')

        return {
            color: randomColor,
            // other style attributes, see documentation
        }
    },
    onEachFeature: function popUp(feature, layer) {
        var out = [];
        if (feature.properties) {
            for (var key in feature.properties) {
                out.push(key + ": " + feature.properties[key]);
            }
            layer.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
        }
    }
});
```

[Link to the documentation of leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html)

### edit

Since you want the styles and name of the original shapefile, as your comment suggests.

---

for the name, you need to process it yourself (remove the extention, path name...) then use the result as key of the layers object.
Something like this can be a basic start

```js
var name = base.split(".")[0]; // if base is the file name and can change

var overlays = {};
overlays[name] = geo // this way the name can be dynamic
```

---

About styles,
There is not much documentation on the library you used to parse shps (assuming its [shpjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shpjs)
but if they are implemented it should have created a `style` entry in the geojson output. So I bet you need to implement the style function as this :

```js
function style (feature) {
     return feature.style;
}
```

#### full code

```js
var watercolor = L.tileLayer('http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {});
var geo = L.geoJson({features: []}, {
    style: function style (feature) { return feature.style },
    onEachFeature: function popUp(feature, layer) {
        var out = [];
        if (feature.properties) {
            for (var key in feature.properties) {
                out.push(key + ": " + feature.properties[key]);
            }
            layer.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
        }
    }
});

var myMap = L.map('divMapID', {
    center: L.latLng(39.15097955985934, 9.019421210403138), //Valori
    prec: [39, 9],
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 3,

    layers: [watercolor, geo]

});


//data è un oggetto geoJson
var base = 'testo.zip';
shp(base).then(function (data) {
    geo.addData(data);
});

var name = base.split('.')[0] // get the name of the file 
// you will need to improve this part 

var baseMaps = {
    "BaseLayer": watercolor
};
var overlays = {};
overlays[name] = geo; // add the layer with name as key

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(myMap);
```

#### note

I don't have what it takes to test it right now, could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is the reading of the shapefile does not reflect its real properties. Shape in QGIS has properties for each single point,coordinates,colors. The first image is obtained by uploading my shapefile to the link: http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#10/39.1002/8.8152. In this case the real properties of the file are read with its real name and with its colors and so I would like my file to be read in the same way. My concern is also because the properties that I print in the popup are read while the colors of the points and the name of the shapefile are not read.

Comment: I edited the post according to your comment.

Comment: The name of the file takes it correctly and it would be fine for me already, even if I would need the name of the layer of shapefile not the name of the file. The name of my shapefile is test.zip and the name of the layer is "idrico sup".The code of the style of the markers does not work, at least in this writing, I also tried to modify the call to the style function a little but it does not work.I can send my file for a test.